# Why is my lambda taking exactly 6 seconds every time to respond?

Tags: aws-lambda, async-await, serverless

I am using NodeJS env with serverless framework.

The service is an endpoint for a contact form submission. Code looks something like this.
I have two async calls, one is writing to dynamoDB and another is sending an Email via SES.

```
module.exports.blog = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const handler = 'AB';
  const sesParams = getSesParams(handler, data);

  if (typeof data.text !== 'string') {
    callback(null, validationErrRes);
    return;
  }

  try {
    await logToDB(handler, data);
  } catch (dbErr) {
    console.error(dbErr);
    callback(null, errRes(dbErr, 'Failed to log to DB'));
    return;
  }

  try {
    await SES.sendEmail(sesParams).promise();
  } catch (emailErr) {
    console.error(emailErr);
    callback(null, errRes(emailErr, 'Failed to send mail'));
    return;
  }

  callback(null, succsessResponse);
  return;
};
```

The response takes exactly 6sec when the dbput and sendMail takes total of < 300ms.
[image]

PS: Running both async calls parallelly does not help much.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the callback in your function definition and the call to your callback function. Just return the successResponse. You are already an async function so do not need to use a callback. You can also just return error.

`module.exports.blog = async (event, context) => {`

and

```
return {
   statusCode: 200
}
```

and

```
return validationErrRes
```